# How to scan a website and build a sitemap using Node.js

Tags: node.js, sitemap

I am trying to get a website's sitemap using Node.js. Could anyone point me to how can I do that?

I am currently looking at https://github.com/cgiffard/node-simplecrawler but am not sure how to stop it from actually crawling the page. I only need the links, and possibly in a structured object ...

I hope that's clear!

Cheers,
H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very useful command line tool for doing exactly that, written in node. I found its source code very useful in that task. Here is a link to package's repository: https://github.com/lgraubner/node-sitemap-generator-cli

Here is the code I ended up using:

```
var Crawler = require('simplecrawler');

var port = 80;
var exclude = ['gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'ico', 'bmp', 'ogg', 'webp',
  'mp4', 'webm', 'mp3', 'ttf', 'woff', 'json', 'rss', 'atom', 'gz', 'zip',
  'rar', '7z', 'css', 'js', 'gzip', 'exe'];
var exts = exclude.join('|');
var regex = new RegExp('\.(' + exts + ')', 'i'); // This is used for filtering crawl items.
var crawler = new Crawler('www.website.com'); 

var pages = []; // This array will hold all the URLs

// Crawler configuration
crawler.initialPort = port;
crawler.initalPath = '/';

crawler.addFetchCondition(function (parsedURL) {
  return !parsedURL.path.match(regex); // This will reject anything that's not a link.
});

// Run the crawler
crawler.start();

crawler.on('fetchcomplete', function(item, responseBuffer, response) {
  pages.push(item.url); // Add URL to the array of pages
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure but i wasn't happy with that tool , 
I wrote some code using  crawler package, It builds a sitemap , automaticly

```
    var Crawler = require("crawler");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');




var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output');
writeStream.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">');

var strBuff = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">';



var Router = require('routes');
var router = Router();
var noop = function(){};

var peroid = {
    '/':'hourly',
    '/results':'hourly',
    '/tips': 'hourly',
    '/tips/:country':'hourly',
    '/tips/:country/:venue':'hourly',
    '/support':'hourly',

}


function addToMap(url) {
    var key = router.match(url.replace('https://www.yourwebsite.com',''));
    if(!key) {
        key = {};
        key.route =  '/';
    } else {
        console.log('match ', url);
    }
    var route = key.route;
    var freq = peroid[route];
    var buf = '<url>\n<loc>'+url+'</loc>\n <changefreq>'+freq+'</changefreq>\n<priority>0.5</priority>\n</url>';
    strBuff += '<url>\n<loc>'+url+'</loc>\n <changefreq>'+freq+'</changefreq>\n<priority>0.5</priority>\n</url>';

    writeStream.write(buf);

}

function saveTofile() {
    console.log('end');
    writeStream.write('\n</urlset>');
    writeStream.end();
}



router.addRoute("/", noop);
router.addRoute("/tips", noop);
router.addRoute("/tips/:country", noop);
router.addRoute("/tips/:country/:venue", noop);
router.addRoute("/support", noop);
router.addRoute("/algorithm", noop);





var cache = {};

var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections : 25,
    skipDuplicates: true,
    // This will be called for each crawled page
    onDrain: function () {
        console.log('ondrain');
        saveTofile();
    },
    callback : function (error, result, $) {
        if(error || !$) {
            console.log(error, result.uri);
            return;
        }
        $('a').each(function(index, a) {
            var toQueueUrl = $(a).attr('href');
            if(!toQueueUrl) {
                return;
            }

            if((toQueueUrl && toQueueUrl[0] !== '/') || toQueueUrl.indexOf('/api/') !== -1 || toQueueUrl.indexOf('.pdf') !== -1) {
                //console.log('not crawliing', toQueueUrl);
                return;
            }
            if(cache.hasOwnProperty(toQueueUrl) || !toQueueUrl) {
                return;
            }
            //console.log(toQueueUrl);
            c.queue('https://www.yourwebsite.com'+toQueueUrl);

            addToMap('https://www.yourwebsite.com'+toQueueUrl);

            cache[toQueueUrl]  = 1;

            var keyz = Object.keys(cache);
            if(! (keyz.length % 100) ) {
                console.log('total', keyz.length);
            }
        });
    }
});


c.queue('https://www.yourwebsite.com');
```

Hope it helps u